# Ruby: increment all integers in a string by +1

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I am looking for a succinct way to increment all the integers found in a string by +1 and return the full string.

For example:

```
"1 plus 2 and 10 and 100"
```

needs to become

```
"2 plus 3 and 11 and 101"
```

I can find all the integers very easily with

```
"1 plus 2 and 10 and 100".scan(/\d+/)
```

but I'm stuck at this point trying to increment and put the parts back together.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the [block form of String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001186):

```
str = "1 plus 2 and 10 and 100".gsub(/\d+/) do |match|
  match.to_i + 1
end

puts str
```

Output:

```
2 plus 3 and 11 and 101
```

Comment: Sweet! I knew there was a super simple way to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The `gsub` method can take in a block, so you can do this

```
>> "1 plus 2 and 10 and 100".gsub(/\d+/){|x|x.to_i+1}
=> "2 plus 3 and 11 and 101"
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing with your regex is that it doesn't preserve your original string in the chain in order to put it back. What I did was to split it using spaces, detect which are words or integers using `w.to_i != 0` (not counting 0 as an integer, you might want to improve this), add one, and join it back:

```
s = "1 plus 2 and 10 and 100"

s.split(" ").map{ |e| if (e.to_i != 0) then e.to_i+1 else e end }.join(" ")
=> "2 plus 3 and 11 and 101"
```